# Calculating Launch Angles for a Projectile With a Constant Wind Force

Tags: projectile-motion

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the azimuth (`a`) and elevation angle (`e`) to have a projectile with a velocity of magnitude `v` hit an arbitrary point (`P_t`) from the origin.

So the velocity vector would be expressed as
$$
v \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \cos(a) \cdot \cos(e) \\ \sin(a) \cdot \cos(e) \\ \sin(e) \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have a constant x-y acceleration acting on the projectile `W` in addition to gravity, so the acceleration vector acting on the projectile would be

\begin{bmatrix} W_x \\ W_y \\ g \end{bmatrix}

My intuition was to use the displacement equation in each of the three axes and solve the system, but I'm not sure exactly how to approach solving the system. Is there a way that this can be solved or approximated??

Comment: There are three unknowns. You also have the time. On all three axis you arrive at $P_t$ simultaneously.

Comment: @Andrei Ah yes, silly me. I updated the question